# Muting a programm on startup. win10

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer, mute

Hello i am on windows 10 and i want some way to ensure a program "xyz.exe" always starts muted.

Examples:

1 - I double click the ".exe" file and start the program. I want it to be muted in the volume mixer and only play sounds once i unmute it in the volume mixer. If i restart my computer with the program unmuted it should be muted on start up.

2 - The program is added to startup programs in the task manager. it should always auto start muted on start up. If i restart with the program unmuted it should start up muted again.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mute this easily with a lightweight Windows utility called [Nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) using the following code in a batch file:

```
start /d "path-to-your-exe-diretory\xyz.exe
Run nircmd snircmd muteappvolume xyz.exe
```

If you want it to always run muted you will have to launch it with this command via batch file. You can create a shortcut for this batch file and place it in your startup folder so that it always starts muted.

Comment: I could also show you a way to map a key to toggle a mute for this program if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i was able to change your code to :

start /D "D:\a\b\c\" xyz.exe 
timeout 1
nircmd muteappvolume xyz.exe 1

this works perfectly for my use case 1, but it doesn't work correctly during system start up.
during system startup the batch file executes, but the muteappvolume command is executed before the program shows up on the volume mixer.
i am having problems getting the muteappvolume command to execute after xyz.exe actually starts.

Comment: throw a delay in there with `SLEEP 10`. If you feel the answer was useful please consider accepting it as the answer.